# Error with Strongly Typed Entity Framework Object in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

Creating the razor view with strongly typed of Entity Framework generated POCO gives the below error.

***The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.***

However i added System.Data, System.Data.Entity dlls into my MVC 3 project.
In case if i use ViewModel object instead of EF Created POCO it is not showing error.

What is the problem of binding Entity Framework object in Razor View?

**Edit:** Reading [Using Entity Model Object in ASP.Net MVC View Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186291/using-entity-model-object-in-asp-net-mvc-view-page) is not helping me. What could i do here, Do i need to create another ViewModel for each POCO?

Comment: 1) Can you post a stack trace? 2) Are you referencing Entity Framework in that project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

To the `<system.web>` section of your web.config

Comment: Thanks. It works! Initially i tried adding with project references. Now moved to web.config section. Also i tried <pages>     <namespaces> section, it was not working :) Thanks for your help. Is any reason why adding in project reference and adding in pages namespace not working?